# When i run the npm run dev function following error is printed on the console

Tags: reactjs, react-usecallback

error ./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-compose-refs/dist/index.mjs
Attempted import error: 'useCallback' is not exported from 'react' (imported as '$3vqmr$useCallback').
does anyone know how to fix this issue

i have tried various solutions from chatgpt nothing worked

Comment: Please provide the source code and the screenshot of the error you see. Only then we can answer.

Comment: Provide additional info.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error after I had run the command `"npm run build"` in my Next js 13 project, I did 2 things

1.

> Delete the build folder

and run your project again, this will eliminate all the above mentioned errors.
OR

2. If you are using VS Code, press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and write `restart` and press enter, most of the errors will be gone.

These steps worked for me, hope they work for you as well.

Thanks :)